# Cannot get a nested for loop to work in javascript but that same loop worked in java

Tags: javascript

I am teaching myself programming and I am doing a Udacity course on Javascript. They have a quiz to create a for loop in a function to create a triangle and call that function in another function. I wrote a for loop (pasted below) that worked in Java but is not working in Javascript. Can you point out my mistake please? The code is only printing 1 "*".

Code I wrote:

```
function makeLine(length){
    var line = "";
    for(var i = 1; i <= length; i++){
        for(var j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            line += "* ";
        }
        return line + "\n";
    }
}

function buildTriangle(input){
    makeLine();
}

console.log(buildTriangle(10));
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is, similarity of names aside, Java and JavaScript have almost nothing in common. Tag with what you're actually using, it helps focus attention.

Comment: Hint: Your `input` argument is given to `buildTriangle` and not passed through, so `makeLine` has no idea what to do.

Comment: You aren't returning `makeLine(input)`, so the function returns undefined. Also, one of your return statements is on the wrong line in `makeLine`

Comment: I'm no Java expert, but I'm pretty sure this didn't work in Java either.  1. Your returning out of the function in the first loop iteration no matter what.  I'm I'm pretty sure Java is the same here.  And second your buildTriangle return nothing, again I'm sure it's the same in Java.

Comment: For Java, i used method call instead of function since I haven't learned how to make functions in Java yet. So i made a method with the nested for loop and another method to call the for loop method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    function makeLine(length) {
      var line = '';
      
      // outer loop is number of lines
      for (var i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
        // inner loop is number of stars for this line
        for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
          line += '* ';
        }
        // after requisite number of stars, add a new line char to end this line, before returning to the outer loop
        line += '\n';
      }
      // return your finished string to the calling function
      return line;
    }
    
    function buildTriangle(input) {
      // need to send "input" to the makeline function
      // since you are not printing here.. you need to return the result of this function
      // to the calling function, so console.log has something to print.
      return makeLine(input);
    
    }
    
    console.log(buildTriangle(10));
```

Also, I might use descriptive variable names instead of `i`, `j` just to make it easier to read, and to add clarity.
For example:
`for (line_num = 1; line_num <= length; line_num++)`
and
`for (star_num = 1; star_num <= line_num; star_num++)`

Comment: You could see the result right here in SO.  Just use the <> to make a snippet.

Comment: ya, thanks @keith.  I realized that soon after posting.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Keith :-D     Thanks !!

Comment: "Also, I might use descriptive variable names [...] to add clarity.", but it does not stink having a function called ```makeLine```, which builds a _triangle_, and having a function called ```buildTriangle``` which does _nothing_? At least ```i``` and ```j``` do not suggest anything false.

Answer (score 0):

`makeLine` dont use `return` in loop, in `buildTriangle` call the `function makeLine` with arg `input` and `return` it

```js
function makeLine(length){
    var line = "";
    for(var i = 1; i <= length; i++){
        for(var j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            line += "* ";
        }
       line += "\n";
    }
     return line;
}

function buildTriangle(input){
  return makeLine(input);
}
console.log(buildTriangle(10));
```

Comment: It's not a triangle, the reason been.. Were you had return, you wanted `line += "\n"` and where you now have `return line + "\n"`, just put `return line;`

Comment: Sorry, I have just copied his example, you are wright. check update

Comment: Nearly, `line += "\n";` :-)  I've just done the edit for you..  ps. not sure why you was down voted.. I'll up vote you.

Comment: He want to break the string in the top loop

Comment: Looking at profile pic, it's a She, not a He.. :)  Also not sure what you mean break the string in top loop..   Anyway, modified your snippet to work.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I must be more careful.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the name **makeLine** I am rather convinced that you are supposed to make only a single line there, then make a triangle by repeatedly calling from **buildTriangle**:

```js
function makeLine(length){
  var line='';
  for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
    line+="*";
  line+="\n";
  return line;
}

function buildTriangle(input){
  var tri="";
  for(var j=0;j<input;j++)
    tri+=makeLine(j+1);
  return tri;
}

console.log(buildTriangle(5));
```